# nose runs tests twice

Tags: python, nose

I am trying to run test with nose and here is project structure:

```
ForTest
├── test_module
│   └── test_suite.py
└── test_runner.py
```

test_suite.py contains:

```
def test_1():
    pass


def test_2():
    pass
```

and test_runner.py contains next:

```
import nose

nose.main(argv=['','-v']).run_and_exit()
```

when I run test_runner.py I have next content in output:

```
test_suite.test_1 ... ok
test_suite.test_2 ... ok
test_suite.test_1 ... ok
test_suite.test_2 ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.002s

OK
```

Nose runs tests twice. If I connect myself plugin, I can see, for example, that mehtod addSuccess() calls 4 times. Could you explain me, why do I get this behaviour and how can I prevent it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can rename your `test_runner.py` to `runner.py`, this way nose does not treat your test runner as a test itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using setup_module() and teardown_module() in your test file and define: 
@with(setup_module,teardown_module)

def test_1():

```
pass
```

then you need to remove @with(setup_module,teardown_module) from your file, this is making your tests run twice.